# Understanding the definition of spectral integral by comparing to Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

I found in Conway's functional analysis there is a definition of spectral integral that looks more natural. I have a feeling that this is something similar to the definition of Riemann or Lebesgue integral. I think this might be a paralleled version of Riemann integral we learnt in calculus: "for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every partition of $[a,b]$ with norm $\|P\|<\delta$ and $\xi_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$ be the sample points, then $\left|\sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i)\Delta x_i-A\right|<\epsilon$". However, I can hardly seen the link between "norm condition" I wrote above and the $\sup\{\cdots\}$ condition in the figure below. Can anyone explain how to intutive understand the spectral integral?

[image]

Comment: The spectral measure can be understood as a projection valued Riemann-Stieltjes integral (this has a similar visual interpretation via interval partitions like the Riemann integral). For more details see for example the book by von Neumann

Comment: @s.harp Thanks. But the character of $E$ and $\phi$ seemed not somehow corresponding to the two functions $f,~g$ appears in the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int f(x)\,dg(x)$. By the way, von Neumann had published many books, is [this](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Foundations-Quantum-Mechanics-New/dp/0691178569/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=von+Neumann&qid=1624250801&s=books&sr=1-4) one?

Comment: For a self-adjoint operator $T$ and a function $F$ von Neumann works with $F(T) = \int F(\lambda) dP(\lambda)$ where $P$ is the resolution of the identity associated to the operator $T$ see for example [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator#Resolution_of_the_identity) (very short) explanation. With your notation
$$\langle v,P(\lambda) w\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\lambda 1\, dE_{v,w}$$
where $v,w\in H$ arbitrary. The book I was referring to is indeed that one. I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but it seems to me this may be a more familiar way to understand this.